# Popup window with data from fields (cms page / block)

Tags: php, magento

I want to add button to magento edit cms/block page, that when i click on it it shows popup window with values of input fields from form (eg. Page Title, Page Identifier, Content).

Adding button was easy but i have to get this values form these fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Page in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Edit` and for Block in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Edit` with button you can define onclick js function to be called and in `$this->_formScripts[]` you add that js function. In this js function you can do all magic you want.

A quick example at `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Edit`:

```
public function __construct()
{
    ...
    $this->_addButton('quickview', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Quick Form View'),
                'onclick'   => 'quickview()',
                'class'     => 'info',
            ), -200);
    $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function quickview(){
                f1=document.forms['edit_form'];
                //to show specific element value
                var txt = document.getElementById('page_title').value;
                //to get All elements
                var txt = '';
                for (var i=0; i<f1.length; i++){
                    txt = txt + f1.elements[i].id + ' : ' + f1.elements[i].value + '\\n';
                }
                var popupDiv = document.createElement('div');
                var popupHtml = '<div id =\"popup\" style=\"position: absolute; width: 94%; padding: 10px; z-index: 10; left: 28px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(248, 248, 248); display: block; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);\"></div>';
                popupHtml+='<div style=\"background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px rgb(0, 0, 0); left: 0px; min-height: 250%; min-width: 100%; opacity: 0.45; position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 9; display: block;\" ></div>';
                popupDiv.innerHTML = popupHtml;
                f1.appendChild(popupDiv);
                document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = txt;
            }
        ";


}
```

Comment: This is getting data form forms

f1=document.forms['edit_form'];

Is there a way to get data that is exiting form post ?

Comment: yes, edit form already have all data. If you need some information that is not available in Form then you can just fire ajax in same js method to get data.

Comment: I must locate normal save action, copy it and remove part that saves data, but return to edit page with data

Comment: This script get data from forms.
But when i click "save button" - data get posted. What if some script edit that data when posting ? Then my values from inputs are different then values that goes to database. I was wondering is there a way to get data "after post" but without actually posting it :-)

Comment: If you looking for safe place to display this popup without saving any information,then You should be doing this on CMS/Pages grid. Like Action column have link to preview for all sms pages. You can provide and quick view link that that pops up information without any other action. Did I get it correct?